# Relay open and close switch button automatically

Tags: switches, button, toggle-switch

I have a very simple circuit which consists of a battery, a load (lamp), and a button (on-off).

I want to a very simple and cheap (without Arduino or microcontroller) way to open and close the circuit automatically when the button is on and stop when button is off.

Press (ON), the lamp lights up (close) then after 2 s the lamp goes off (open) automatically. Repeat this process continuously untill I press off so the circuit is open and the light off.

Battery voltage: 7.4 V @ 1 A
Lamp power: 3 W

[image]

I want it to be like this:

https://www.veed.io/view/e259be3c-cfdb-4675-9cd0-4856a02f5e67?sharingWidget=true

Comment: We need many more details.  What is the battery voltage?  What is the lamp current or wattage?

Comment: The text of your question is confusing at best. Please edit so it makes more sense. You talk about a "button" but show a "switch" in the schematic. You also talk about pressing on the "lamp" which does not make much sense. Also need to clarify if the "'switch" is a momentary or alternate action device.

Comment: So - you want a [Flasher Relay](https://www.amazon.com/Vehicle-Blinker-Light-Flasher-0-02-20A/dp/B00BLZ9XQK)?

Comment: that is a long way to say that you want the lamp to flash when the switch is closed

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand the "after 2 seconds" portion, but essentially I think you're asking for a latching relay?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relay#Latching_relay

This essentially toggles the output when the input is activated. This means; when the input (button) is activated, the output switches to the opposite state, of what it currently is.

If you are looking for a timer function, a latching relay can be combined with (or replaced by) a timed relay (for example "off delay").